# Suppose $F$ and $G$ are families of sets. Prove that if $F ⊆ G$ then $∪F ⊆ ∪G$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

**My attempt:**

Suppose $ x\in \cup F$. It means $\exists $ some set $A_0 \in F$, such that $x  \in A_0$. It also means, that $A_0 \in G$(since$F \subseteq G$). We know, that $\exists (A_0 \in F) \subseteq G$ and it shows, that there is arbitrary set in $F$ that is also in $G$. Therefore, $\cup F \subseteq \cup G$

Can you please check the logic of the proof? If it's clear or maybe it's possible somehow to improve it?

Comment: You don't have "$x\in G$(since $F\subseteq G$)". I suppose/hope, you mean $A_0\in G$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are right. It was a misprint. I corrected it

Comment: You clearly have the right idea, though your writing leaves much to be desired. Frankly, the bit saying $\exists (A_0 \in F) \subseteq G$ is nonsense, though I understand what your are trying to say. Better replace the whole sentence starting with “We know” by something like this: Thus we have $x\in A_0\in G$, and therefore $x\in\bigcup G$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen thank you for an advice:)